# Line break with CoreText

Tags: ios, core-text

I am trying to adjust the paragraph style settings in CoreText in order to let lines flow nicely. I want to wrap a line by word, but it's not working.

These are my settings, I am not pasting the whole code since the variable names are self-explanatory and reflect the settings in iOS.

```
_firstLineHeadIndent = 0.0;
_defaultTabInterval = 36.0;
_baseWritingDirection = kCTWritingDirectionNatural;
_alignment = kCTNaturalTextAlignment;
_lineHeightMultiple = 0.0;
_minimumLineHeight = 0.0;
_maximumLineHeight = 10.0;
_paragraphSpacing = 0.0;
_listIndent = 0;
_lineBreakMode = kCTLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```

I attach a screenshot to illustrate more clearly what I mean.

[image: Not filling line]

Comment: It looks as if you have hard line breaks in your source data - you need to get rid of them

Comment: Thank you! Sometimes it's so simple. I think I will preprocess the files before loading them.